# What is the TPM 2.0 update?

Tags: tpm

Every time I start my computer and/or the package updater, I get a message about a TPM 2.0 update going from version `1.3.0.1` to `1.3.1.0`. However when I apply the update and reboot, the computer has fails to boot and breaks.

When I finally get the computer in a usable state again, the update is there again, with the bothersome notification yet again.

What is this update and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Error message during update request to "clear ownership"
update is ok after I tick something inside bios related with "Intel trusted execution technology" called "TXT", sorry if it's not clear: I did it a few days ago.

Hope it help.

Comment: Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To install the update, you have to clear TPM owner information. In order to do that, go to the BIOS (press F2 during boot), open Settings -> Security -> TPM 2.0 Security. Check Clear option and confirm your action. Once owner information is cleared install the update again. This time it should finish successfully.

Just please note that your system may keep important data in TPM module (as for example, a password to your hard disk) and once you clear it you may lost access to your files...

Comment: Is there a way to see what kind of information is stored in the TPM? I have full disk encryption enabled and I assume, this might be one of the cases where crucial information is stored in TPM. Can I install the update without loosing access to my data?

Comment: If you use Linux, there is a high chance that you don't use TPM for storing keys used to encrypt your disk. If you are sure that you do, and your keys are stored in TPM, then see [this link](https://github.com/morbitzer/linux-luks-tpm-boot/blob/master/README.md), especially the 'Booting if something went wrong' section.

If you use Windows, then you should use Windows Defender to reset TPM. See [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/initialize-and-configure-ownership-of-the-tpm).