# Why do firmware updates not apply?

Tags: updates, uefi, update-manager, xps, firmware

I cannot get firmware updates to apply on a Dell XPS 9360 running Ubuntu 18.04. Files are copied to the boot partition and found upon reboot, but **the update does not seem to be applied after the reboot has finished.**

### Update procedure

I recently upgraded this laptop from 16.04 to 18.04 and for the first time I received a notification that firmware updates are available. Clicking the notification opens *Ubuntu Software* which shows the available updates:

- Version 1.3.1.0 for *XPS 13 9360 TPM 2.0*
- Version 0.2.9.0 for *XPS 13 9360 System Firmware*

After pressing <kbd>Update All</kbd> in *Ubuntu Software*, I can confirm (in a terminal) that `*.cab` files have been copied to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fw/` and I get asked to reboot.

During reboot, a short messages confirms that the update files are found and the screen blinks a few times. To me this seems as if the system switches into update modes and applies the updates before completing the reboot.

### Failed result

Afterwards, the system boots normally into Ubuntu but updates do not seem to have been applied:

- *Ubuntu Software* still lists the same updates
- `fwupdmgr` still lists the same updates
- `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` still shows the old version 2.2.1 instead of 2.9.0
- `cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/ppi/version` shows version 1.3 instead of 1.3.1 (I don't know for sure if this is a valid way to check the firmware version of TPM; when trying to install `tpm-tools`, starting *trousers.service* failed)

### Attempted alternatives

- [Trying with `fwupdmgr`](https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/) lead to the same results: Files end up in boot partition and are found upon reboot but do not get applied.
- Booting into update manager and manually selecting the `*.cap` files fails as well (could select the file but not proceed because the button stayed grayed out)

My question remains: **How can I apply the firmware updates offered by *Ubuntu Software* and `fwupdmgr`?**

Comment: I posted a partial answer to my problem but I won't mark it as the solution yet, because I am hoping for full solutions.

Comment: After waiting several months and trying again, the update now applied. I don't know what happened in between, but most likely some software update fixed the underlying issue.

Comment: the same happens now for me and 20.04

Answer (score 3):

I found [this troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/rhboot/fwupdate/wiki/Debugging-UEFI-Capsule-updates#i-am-doing-multiple-updates-and-it-fails) by the developers of `fwupdate` which suggests to try to apply updates one by one:

> #### Booting into fwupx64.efi but nothing happens
>
> Are you applying multiple capsules simultaneously? This could mean doing a TPM update and BIOS update at the same time, or an FMP update and BIOS update at the same time.
>   I am doing multiple updates and it fails
>
> 1. Re-run the cleanup systemd unit.
>
>    - You'll need to remove a state file (in /var/lib/fwupdate/done or somewhere similar - distro dependent)
>    - This removes the payloads from EFI system partition, Boot entries and all NVRAM variables.
> 2. Re-run just one update at a time. If this fixes your problem, please report an issue with the relevant details.

Following these steps I succeeded to install the system firmware update:

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr clear-offline
$ sudo fwupdmgr clear-history
$ sudo fwupdmgr install ${HOME}/.cache/fwupdmgr/afddc660b9a0f8045feaa4703f8258a5d197dad1-Signed_1152921504627781711.cab
```

After a reboot, the DELL system firmware updated itself.

I was not able to also install the TPM firmware upgrade yet. Maybe the [troubleshooting guide on how to solve issues with applying a single update](https://github.com/rhboot/fwupdate/wiki/Debugging-UEFI-Capsule-updates#only-doing-one-update-and-it-fails) helps in debugging the issue and finding enough information for a bug report. I have not tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to apply the System firmware update by clearing the fwupd history and applying the System firmware update alone.

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1020852/659134), you need to clear the TPM owner information before applying the TPM 2.0 firmware update. But, you may lose access to your files by doing this, so please perform a backup and verify it first.

Comment: The TPM update issue has been solved in the latest version of fwupd: https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/689

Comment: I confirm. The TPM 2.0 firmware update works correctly with version 1.2.5 of fwupd.