# How to check if TPM2.0 is owned and if TPM is enabled in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ownership, tpm

Is there any command to check if **TPM2.0** is owned and if **TPM** is enabled on Ubuntu 16.04?

We are using TPM2.0, Intel TXT, Ubuntu 16.04 and DL380Gen10 server.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014058/what-is-the-tpm-2-0-update

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen - Tanks for the replay, but it did not help me to find out ownership details of TPM2.0 and TXT enabled information.